# Creating Mongoose Schema with parameter validation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to create a simple user schema with mongoose and i want to validate some of my fields. It is not clear to me what validation is available to me when reading the documentation, i am wondering if someone can point me in the right direction where to read about all validation options available to me?

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
    trim: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },

});
```

For example, i would like to know if i can declare minimum character length on my email property. I know this can be done with maxChar: etc. or something but i cant find the part in their documentation where it talks about this?

Answer (score 0):

After some writing this question i finally found the part in mongoose documentation that i was looking for.

Here is the part about the validation parameters available to mongoose Schemas 
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#strings